# How to use variable variables inside of requirejs module

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm updating an old project to now use requirejs. I have a method which dynamically calls other methods. Before, my App was registered in the global scope so the below code worked. Now that my App is now a module, window['App'] is undefined.

How can I check if an unknown method exists on my App module from within the module itself?

```
var App = {
    run: function(name, args) {
        if(typeof window['App'][name] == 'function') {
            window['App'][name].apply(undefined, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I now feel silly for not trying this sooner.

```
var App = {
    run: function(name, args) {
        if(typeof this[name] == 'function') {
            this[name].apply(undefined, args);
        }
    }
}
```